# Don't have method listtransactio

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

[bitcoin core version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stTiL.png)

[Trying to use listtransactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMYHb.png)

I don't understand why my bitcoin core don't have this method. How add this method to core?

I installed the node using this guide: https://baloian.medium.com/how-to-setup-and-run-a-bitcoin-full-node-on-ubuntu-a106fb86dbb3

Answer (score 0):

1. In your screenshot the bitcoin-core version is equal to **23.99.0-something**. You should build or download binaries of the latest release which is [23.0](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases/tag/v23.0).
2. In order to use [listtransactions](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listtransactions.html) you need:

- bitcoin core daemon running `bitcoind --daemon`
- created/loaded a wallet `bitcoin-cli createwallet "sometag"`
- then you can `bitcoin-cli listtransactions` which will return an empty array in my case because the wallet is new

[official build notes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md)
[download bitcoin-core](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/)
[running a full node](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node)
[personal gist to download and install bitcoin core on linux x86_64](https://gist.github.com/ethicnology/d6359fb0ca8c98477443cbe23160e84c#file-bitcoin-full-node-sh=)